# Derivative of a curve's velocity vector

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Why is that in the equation below the second derivative of the position vector has a minus in the middle instead of plus after the product rule? I didn't get why we can just replace - sign in front of *a* if that's the reason.

[image]

where;

[image]

Comment: Alright got it. Forgot the sign in front of y component (i.e. S) in the second derivative, which makes both C and S have the negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

Just the chain rule.

Note that $\dot{r}(t)=(aC'(t),S'(t))^T$.

Also, $C(t)=\cos\big(\pi-(1-\cos\omega t)\big)$ and
$$
C'(t)=-\sin\big(\pi-(1-\cos\omega t)\big)\cdot \pi \sin(\omega t)\cdot\omega
=\omega \pi\sin(\omega t)\cdot (-S(t))
$$